# How to dynamically load strategies (Strategy Pattern)?

Tags: java, sql, dynamic, strategy-pattern

My application will have different strategies for my objects. What is the best way to implement that? Ideally, I would like to dynamically load the strategy implementations from, say, some relational database. I'm not sure how to do that, though. What's the best approach?

For instance, say that we want to apply strategy `Strategy123` to object `MyObj`: we just load the object from a database, using its ID `123`, deserialize it, get the Strategy class, and use it with `MyObj`.

This approach could have some issues when it comes to maintenance: while it sounds easier at a first glance, it can be a pain in the long run, for example if the strategies' interfaces change.

What other solutions do I have? I would like a solution that allows me to keep the strategy classes outside the codebase, so that I don't need to modify code and re-deploy the application if my Strategy changes, or if I add a new strategy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement the strategy using rules engine like [Drools](http://www.jboss.org/drools) or some scripting language like [Groovy](http://groovy.codehaus.org) and store these in database. Then you can load these rules from database at runtime and apply those on your object.

Comment: How can we do that with Groovy ? Can you give me an example I am very interested to learn it.